# Charpit's Method of a function F(Z,P,Q)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In one of my textbook, I find an example which is $p^2 z^2+q^2-1=0$

And there the given solution is 
$\frac{dx}{2pz^2} = \frac{dy}{2q} = \frac{dz}{2p^2z^2+2q^2} = \frac{dp}{-2p^3z} = \frac{dq}{-2p^2qz}$

Afterthat $q=ap$ and $p=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+a^2}}$ where a is constant and then proceed further.

I didn't understand where does this $q=ap$ come from?

Apology: Actually, I am learning this method by myself from last 2 hrs. So my concept is not fully clear yet.

If somebody helps me then I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dp}{-2p^3z} = \frac{dq}{-2p^2qz}\quad\to\quad \frac{dp}{p} = \frac{dq}{q}\quad\to\quad \ln|q|=\ln|p|+\text{constant}\quad\to\quad q=ap$$